# Unable to connect to google cloud platform instance via SFTP with Filezilla

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know the proper way to connect Filezilla SFTP to WordPress Instance on Google's Compute Engine?

I generated the SSH keys and input it into Filezilla but it connects and then kicks me out.

I have tried following all the documentation provided by Google Cloud Platform:

- [Connecting to Linux Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardsshblog.sandeepdinesh.com/2015/04/how-to-setup-filezilla-for-google.html)
- [Generating a new SSH key-pair](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#generatesshkeypair)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use vague terms like *"kicks me out"*. Be exact! Show us exact error message and FileZilla log file.